# For loop counter is resetting in an internal while loop. Showing a fixed value in while loop and not a changing one

Tags: python, excel, regex, for-loop, while-loop

The idea of the code is to first grab some data from an excel sheet and modify it, then cross compare it with a text document. The code below continues in conjunction with the code below it.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook1 = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Imports.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook1.add_worksheet()
workbook2 = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Modified.xlsx')
worksheet2 = workbook2.add_worksheet()

workbook1.close()
workbook2.close()

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font
import re
    
df1 = pd.read_excel('Employees.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols="B",)

writer=pd.ExcelWriter('Imports.xlsx')

# Writing dataframes into columns
df1.to_excel(writer,index=False,startcol=0)
writer.save()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Imports.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

i = 0
print("Text replacement part 1 of 4")
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        s = ws.cell(r,c).value 
        if s != None and re.search('^Mr ',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub('^Mr ','',s,flags=re.I)
                
        if s != None and re.search('^Ms ',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub('^Ms ','',s,flags=re.I)
                
        if s != None and re.search('^Mrs ',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub('^Mrs ','',s,flags=re.I)
                
        if s != None and re.search('^Miss ',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub('^Miss ','',s,flags=re.I)
                
        if s != None and re.search('^s ',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub('^s ','',s,flags=re.I)                

# Text replacement for list so names in are same format
print("Text replacement part 2 of 4")
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        s = ws.cell(r,c).value                
        if s != None and re.search(' \(S\)$',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub(' \(S\)','',s,flags=re.I)
                
        if s != None and re.search(' \(F\)$',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub(' \(F\)','',s,flags=re.I)
                
          
# Text replacement for list so names in are same format
print("Text replacement part 3 of 4") 
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        s = ws.cell(r,c).value                      
        if s != None and re.search('  ',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub('  ',' ',s,flags=re.I)  
                
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        s = ws.cell(r,c).value
        if s != None and re.search(' $',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub(' $','',s,flags=re.I)
                
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        s = ws.cell(r,c).value
        if s != None and re.search('^ ',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub('^ ','',s,flags=re.I)

print("Text replacement part 4 of 4")
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        s = ws.cell(r,c).value
        if s != None and re.search('^D ',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub('^D ','',s,flags=re.I)
                
for r in range(1,ws.max_row+1):
    for c in range(1,ws.max_column+1):
        s = ws.cell(r,c).value
        if s != None and re.search(' \(L\)$',s,flags=re.I): 
                ws.cell(r,c).value = re.sub(' \(L\)$','',s,flags=re.I)
                ws.cell(r,3).value = ws.cell(r,c).value
                ws.cell(r,c).value = ''
                
ws['C1'].value = 'Not Employed'                
ws['C1'].font = Font(bold=True)   
                
# Saving another file      
wb.save('Imports.xlsx')

writer2=pd.ExcelWriter('Modified.xlsx')

fs1 = pd.read_excel('Imports.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols="A")
fs1 = fs1.sort_values(['ALL_NAME'],ascending=[True])

fs1.to_excel(writer2,index=False,startcol=0)

writer2.save()
count = 0
count2 = 0




#read input file
fin = open("users.txt", "rt")
#read file contents to string
data = fin.read()
#replace all occurrences of the required string
data = data.replace('  Full name: ', '')
data = data.replace('  Account disabled: ', '')
data = data.replace('  User login: ','')
#close the input file
fin.close()
#open the input file in write mode
fin = open("users.txt", "wt")
#overrite the input file with the resulting data
fin.write(data)
#close the file
fin.close()


wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook("Modified.xlsx")
ws1 = wb1["Sheet1"]

test = 0




searchfile = open("users.txt", "r") 
    #print(ws1.cell(r,1).value)
   

for i, line in enumerate(searchfile):
    global match
    match = 0
    global a 
    a = i
    l = searchfile.readline(i)
    # finding first search boundary 
    if re.search('^  dn: ',l,flags=re.I):
        if match == 0:
            boole = True
            while boole == True:
                l3 = searchfile.readline(a)
                # finding end boundary in the file for data
                if re.search('  objectclass: ',l3,flags=re.I):
                    boole = False
                else:
                    a+=1
```

Basically the following code is where the issue pops up. I want the code to iterate the whole excel file and compare each cell with each line within the defined boundaries in the text file. However the value **r** inside the while loop is being reset to 2, whereas before it enters the while loop it seems to be working just fine.

```
        for r in range(2,ws1.max_row+1):
            #print(r)
            while i < a:
                #print(r)
                l2 = searchfile.readline(i)
            
                if re.search("soa$",l2,flags=re.I) and match == 0: 
                    match = 1
                elif re.search('TC$',l2,flags=re.I) and match == 0:
                    match = 1
                elif re.search(l2,ws1.cell(r,1).value,flags=re.I) and match == 0:
                    ws1.cell(r,2).value = "MATCH"
                    match = 1
                
                i+=1
                
            if match == 0:
                ws1.cell(r,4).value = "NO MATCH"

                    
searchfile.close()
wb1.save("Modified.xlsx")
```

When printing `r` in the while loop it contains a value of 2 and outside the while loop but still in the for loop it works as intended. I don't know why this value is not being translated in the while loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think however many 2s you are getting is the number of loops your while loop undergoes. I can't see what "a" is initialized to, but I do see that you never reset "i" inside the for loop. It's going in the for loop, r =2 once, it's going into the while loop r=2 however many times it loops, then back to the for loop where r now =3, and never into the while loop again because i is now permanently greater than a.

Comment: The idea is that in the first for loop the script grabs a certain range of text from lines in the text file between 'i' and 'a', and checks every line in that range with every row in ws1 (in the second for loop and while loop). The 'i' is not reset as once it has been incremented... the second iteration (from the first for loop) will continue from the newly generated value of 'i' and 'a' is then reset based on the new value of 'i' rather than 'i' being reset, this is because the text file has to be fully iterated and this continues progress through the text file. Therefore 'a' > 'i' always

Comment: If you want 'a' to be reset based on the new 'i' then it needs to happen after the for but before the while.